# Need help in improving query performance of SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization

The stored procedure is taking too long to return the results and I want to improve the performance of the stored procedure. But I am not sure where exactly the issue is occurring. Can anyone help by rewriting the subquery after EXISTS clause.

Just for your information, the tables have hundreds of thousands of records

```
DECLARE @InvNo VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,

SELECT @InvNo='123'

DECLARE @tblInv TABLE (RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                         InvNo VARCHAR(MAX))

IF @InvNo IS NOT NULL
    INSERT INTO @tblInv(InvNo)
    SELECT value
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(@InvNo,',')

 
select * from table1 t
where (@InvNo IS NULL
           OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM @tblInv i
                    INNER JOIN table2 inv   
                            ON inv.inv_no = i.InvNo OR ISNULL(inv.alt_inv_no,'@@') = i.InvNo                                
                    INNER JOIN table3 isp
                            ON isp.inv_no = inv.inv_no
                    INNER JOIN table4 ic
                            ON ic.inv_no = inv.inv_no                                               
                         WHERE isp.bl_no = t.bl_no
                           AND ic.cust_code = t.cust_code) 
                )
```

Comment: We're still missing that execution plan we ask you from in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67903249/need-help-in-improving-query-performance). Also, what is a "lakh"?

Comment: The issue is probably the `OR` in the subquery.

Comment: `OR ISNULL(inv.alt_inv_no,'@@')` is not going to be SARGable though. Handle your `NULL` values properly with `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`. Do you *really* need all those `JOIN`'s in the `EXISTS` too?

Comment: @Larnu Yes I really need those JOINS. Removing OR and adding an additional EXISTS seemed to work for me if InvNo has single value or No Value.... For comma separated values, the query is slowing down again..

Comment: Please remember that most of us that are not from India have no idea what a "lac" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having any additional information, I would suggests splitting the `exists` into two separate conditions:

```
select *
from table1 t
where @InvNo IS NULL OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM @tblInv i JOIN
                   table2 inv   
                   ON inv.inv_no = i.InvNo JOIN                              
                   table3 isp
                   ON isp.inv_no = inv.inv_no JOIN
                   table4 ic
                   ON ic.inv_no = inv.inv_no                                               
              WHERE isp.bl_no = t.bl_no AND ic.cust_code = t.cust_code 
             ) OR
     EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM @tblInv i JOIN
                   table2 inv   
                   ON inv.alt_inv_no = i.InvNo JOIN                              
                   table3 isp
                   ON isp.inv_no = inv.inv_no JOIN
                   table4 ic
                   ON ic.inv_no = inv.inv_no                                               
              WHERE isp.bl_no = t.bl_no AND ic.cust_code = t.cust_code 
             );
```

`OR` usually kills the performance of `JOIN`s.

Then be sure you have indexes on all the `JOIN` keys.

Comment: Thank you Gordon.. You are a genius. You saved me. You were right.. The OR was the culprit. :)

Comment: The performance is better after your suggestion. But if the @InvNo is a comma separated value, the time is again longer than the original query :(

Comment: @ArpitaDutta . . . (1) Comma separated values are just a problem in general and you should not be using them.  (2) This answers the question that you asked here.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question and be clear on the differences from this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query,
Major issue with EXISTS clause and OR clause

As one of the condition in OR clause is with variable we can divide code into two parts and No need to have both IS NULL and exists logics in the same query.
It would be good to load the joining columns from exists clause into temp table and inner join with major table might give better performance.

```
SELECT @InvNo='123'

DECLARE @tblInv TABLE 
(RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, InvNo VARCHAR(MAX))
     
IF @InvNo IS NULL
BEGIN
    select * from table1 t
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tblInv(InvNo)
    SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@InvNo,',')
    
SELECT DISTINCT isp.bl_no,ic.cust_code INTO #T
      FROM @tblInv i
    INNER JOIN table2 inv   
            ON inv.inv_no = i.InvNo                              
    INNER JOIN table3 isp
            ON isp.inv_no = inv.inv_no
    INNER JOIN table4 ic
            ON ic.inv_no = inv.inv_no
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT isp.bl_no,ic.cust_code
      FROM @tblInv i
    INNER JOIN table2 inv   
            ON ISNULL(inv.alt_inv_no,'@@') = i.InvNo                                
    INNER JOIN table3 isp
            ON isp.inv_no = inv.inv_no
    INNER JOIN table4 ic
            ON ic.inv_no = inv.inv_no

    select * from table1 t
    INNER JOIN #T T2 ON T2.bl_no = t.bl_no AND T2.cust_code = t.cust_code
END
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But the query which I have mentioned is just a part of a huge stored procedure containing many other queries. I can't rewrite it like the way you have suggested. :(